# Where does one set the Identity 'SetLockoutEndDate' in MVC 5 Framework 4.7.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to enable Lockout in our app. 
In IdentityConfig.cs is the code to set some of the necessary flags.

```
manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
```

I set 'ShouldLockout' to true in the AccountController's "Login" function.

But where does one set the last bit, i.e.

```
manager.SetLockoutEndDate(UserId, manager.DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(50));
```

The setLockoutEndDate, needs the userId. Is that done at registration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting it at RegisterUser and that works.